# Build error when building hono from source code - on project hono-adapter-amqp-vertx: Cannot create docker access object

Tags: docker, maven, eclipse-hono

I was following the documentation here to build hono from source code - [1]: https://www.eclipse.org/hono/docs/dev-guide/building_hono/

But the build fails with this error -

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.33.0:build (build_images) on project hono-adapter-amqp-vertx: Cannot create docker access object : extension (5) should not be presented in certificate_request -> [Help 1]
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.33.0:build (build_images) on project hono-adapter-amqp-vertx: Cannot create docker access object

The docker client version  installed in my machine is 19.03.1 and server version is 19.03.02
java version is 11.0.7

The detailed dump with X option is here - [2]: https://docdro.id/AMRsFem

Please let know how to fix this.

**Updated with more info**

> $ docker info
> Client:
> Debug Mode: false

> Server:
> Containers: 0
> Running: 0
> Paused: 0
> Stopped: 0
> Images: 0
> Server Version: 19.03.12
> Storage Driver: overlay2
> Backing Filesystem: extfs
> Supports d_type: true
> Native Overlay Diff: true
> Logging Driver: json-file
> Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
> Plugins:
> Volume: local
> Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
> Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk >syslog
> Swarm: inactive
> Runtimes: runc
> Default Runtime: runc
> Init Binary: docker-init
> containerd version: 7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
> runc version: dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
> init version: fec3683
> Security Options:
> seccomp
> Profile: default
> Kernel Version: 4.19.130-boot2docker
> Operating System: Boot2Docker 19.03.12 (TCL 10.1)
> OSType: linux
> Architecture: x86_64
> CPUs: 1
> Total Memory: 985.4MiB
> Name: default
> ID: JGCF:FKDA:TRZS:L3E3:U5FP:PUTI:VTXZ:M2TN:PITL:P74X:AMJJ:YRPO
> Docker Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker
> Debug Mode: false
> No Proxy: 192.168.99.100
> Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
> Labels:
> provider=virtualbox
> Experimental: false
> Insecure Registries:
> 127.0.0.0/8
> Live Restore Enabled: false
> Product License: Community Engine

> $ echo $DOCKER_HOST                                                                                                     >tcp://192.168.99.108:2376

Command used to build -

> mvn clean install -Ddocker.host=tcp://192.168.99.108:2376 -Pbuild-docker-image,metrics-prometheus

Comment: What is the output of `docker info` and `echo $DOCKER_HOST` on your machine? What is the exact command line you are using to build Hono?

Comment: I have now updated the results of the command in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be running into [this issue with Java 11.0.7 and TLS 1.3](https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin/issues/1342).

Can you try to use

```sh
mvn clean install -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Ddocker.host=tcp://192.168.99.108:2376 -Pbuild-docker-image,metrics-prometheus
```

to build Hono as described in the issue?